# Using 'via' properly

Tags: grammar, australian-english

I'm an English-learning Japanese student. I want to know if I'm using the word 'via' properly. This is the sentence:

"...by telling Sato how you can meet people even if they live overseas via the application."

Should I have a comma before via, or is this fine now? Thank you for your help!

Comment: "even if they live overseas" is a "parenthetical" and should have commas at both ends.  But the sentence probably should be reworded.

Comment: Would be far better to say "...by telling Sato how you can meet people via the application, even if they live overseas."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"even if they live overseas" is a "parenthetical" and should have commas at both ends.

But the sentence probably should be reworded.
Would be far better to say "...by telling Sato how you can meet people via the application, even if they live overseas."

Answer (score 0):

Konbanwa! You are using via properly.

It's used in the same manner as "with" or "through".

- "...even if they live overseas **via** the application."
- "...even if they live overseas **through** the application."
- "...even if they live overseas **with** the application."
- "...even if they live overseas using the application."

All of these are equally proper (to me).

Comment: Without punctuation the sentence seems to be saying that they live via the application.

Comment: It's a conditional relative clause. I think that it benefits from, but doesn't require, commas. (See my parenthetical there :) )

Comment: "Conditional relative clause" is Greek to me!

Comment: I knew what it was, but I had to look it up the name myself. Examples include: It is a time *when great men are called to act*. People are useful *when necessity calls for it*. It's okay *if you think it is*.

Comment: Regardless of what it is syntactically, it's a *parenthetical* -- placing it in parentheses doesn't change the basic meaning of the sentence.  "...by telling Sato how you can meet people (even if they live overseas) via the application."